# IBM Watson Conversation Client: Child Node Output Not Displaying In Localhost

Tags: node.js, magento, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-functions

I set a loop in my child nodes to loop through my JSON array that is retrieved from IBM Cloud Functions. In 'Try It Now,' it works completely fine, but when I deployed it on a client in localhost, the child node output does not display. Any ideas why?

[image]

The output is in '***Increment***'

In the localhost client, the 'Watson Understands' shows my array values there, it just does not output from the child node. It only outputs the anything_else response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime things are different in the tryout panel than in your app, check two things.
 1. You are passing all the system context back to Watson. 
 when you make your first call to Watson, he will return a context object, your app needs to copy and paste this back with the next message you send in so he knows the state of the conversation
2. You are using the most recent API version. 
I dont think this is the issue here, it sounds like an issue with context, but if results are different this is also another very common reason.

Comment: I would also add. (1) Do not use "Jump To" to go into a branch, use "Skip User Input". (2) Your loop will be disabled after 50 iterations of the same node in the same call (to stop endless loops). So you can never get your counter higher than 50.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to output an image, text and option response type in one output. If I just output text it works, but trying to output image fails.

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the most recent api version? That is the only one that supports the new response types